# How do you get to the very top of the Sun Temple?

Tags: aquaria

After painstakingly finding out that yes, the main character can climb through the vertical pipe in the leftmost area of the Sun Temple through a tight sequence of jumps, I've managed to jump my way to the horizontal pipe between the two topmost chambers. Yay.

However, when I jump from the pipe into the room, I can't quite manage to reach the gears for further exploration. I did try taking speed increasing items, but they haven't helped. When I land on the ground, all of the gears are out of reach (again, speed increasing item don't seem to help here.)

How do you get to the gears in the rightmost, topmost chamber of the suntemple and eventually reach the exit marker at the very top?

I'm not asking what the reward is for pulling this off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gears aren't  quite out of reach.

The lowest one in the middle you can just touch.

If you can jump onto it from the right angle, The right angle is easier to get if you jump onto it wrong a couple of times and let it drop you, you can then jump from that to the gear on the right and back left again to land on top of it, it's then a matter of jumping the other 3 gears, Left, Right Right to get to the exit at the top right.

To better illustrate here's a you tube video of it being done.